# Delete credential mapping with WebLogic Scripting Tool

Tags: weblogic, credentials, wlst

Per Oracle's suggestion, I added a credential mapping to myrealm and attempted to restart all servers.  Now unfortunately, I am unable to restart the admin server or any of the other servers.  At this point, I just want to delete my credential mapping and get with oracle before implementing it.  Does anyone know how to do this with the weblogic scripting tool?

Thanks in advance. (weblogic 12.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from what I read it isn't possible to change security in the WLST.

However, I was able to delete the credential mapping from config.xml and restart the admin servers and all managed servers.